# select without starting 1# and ending #1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `client_id` field that is filled in like this:

```
1#24408926939#1
```

how can I select it without starting 1# and ending #1.
I wanted to use the values ​​of this field in the case without extra characters in it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a codewriting service. Please, show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty regular expression does it by returning the 2nd *substring* that consists of digits (`result_1`). Another option uses `substr + instr` combination and returns substring between two `#` characters (`result_2`).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (client_id) as
  2    (select '1#24408926939#1'     from dual union all
  3     select '42#1412942349#87324' from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select
  6    client_id,
  7    --
  8    regexp_substr(client_id, '\d+', 1, 2) result_1,
  9    --
 10    substr(client_id, instr(client_id, '#', 1, 1) + 1,
 11                      instr(client_id, '#', 1, 2) - instr(client_id, '#', 1, 1) - 1
 12          ) result_2
 13  from test;

CLIENT_ID           RESULT_1            RESULT_2
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
1#24408926939#1     24408926939         24408926939
42#1412942349#87324 1412942349          1412942349

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below SQL and it would help you

```
select replace(replace('1#24408926939#1','#1',''),'1#','') from dual;
```